# Ruby - Join array of objects by an objects field

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects, like so:

```
[
    #<name: "value1", field: "field_A">,
    #<name: "value2", field: "field_B">,
    #<name: "value3", field: "field_C">
]
```

I want as output:

```
"value1 value2 value3"
```

What I am currently doing:

```
variable = ''
array.each { |x| variable << x.name << ' ' }
```

This is ugly, and also leaves an extra space on the end.  I thing Array::join is where I am looking to go, but I can't find a way to access the object fields from it.  Is there another method similar to join that I should be using, or is there another more sensible approach?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
array.map(&:name).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to join an `Array` you should use the `join` method. It takes an optional separator (its default value is `$,` which in turn `nil` by default).

```
array.collect(&:name).join ' '
```

`&:method` syntax is just a shorthand for `{ |x| x.method }`.

Comment: `&:method` is not a special syntax. It is `Symbol#to_proc` that is doing the work.